# Can rails' cells embed their own javascript and css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-cells

I've read several example regarding cells for rails but did not find some example showing how to create a completely isolated widget from a cell.
By isolated, I mean a widget that has its own css / javascript / ... and that only need to be copied in rails folder.
Is that something feasible with a cell ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/apotonick/apotomo

Comment: The README says yes: https://github.com/apotonick/cells#asset-pipeline